# Is the react-native.config.js file required?

Tags: react-native

I was going to add a new font to my project but I just found out that the react-native link has been removed. So I added the fonts manually to the android project it works fine. In this case, do I still need to create the react-native.config.js file?

Comment: No, unless you need any of the config's other features